# Create Self-Signed Root Level Certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have found tutorials in the past for creating self-signed certificates. Now for my personal website (on a virtual server), I want to use a self-signed SSL certificate for logging into my WordPress admin panel. The problem is that I am running multisite; so each site has a different hostname (domain.com, site2.domain.com, site3.domain.com) for the admin panel. Can I create a self-signed certificate that can protect all of the subdomains as well as the root? How do I do that?

Yes, Apache and OpenSSL. The instructions I found are at: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to replace `domain.com` with `*.domain.com` when generating the CSR.

Details for using openssl with apache [found here](http://phaseshiftllc.com/archives/2008/10/27/multiple-secure-subdomains-with-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate)

After you run `openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr`.  It will prompt you for a "Common Name" use `*.domain.com` (where domain.com is your domain name).

More details may be required like are you using apache? And are you using openssl to generate the cert?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I clarified that.

Comment: Did you check out the link I posted.

Comment: Just briefly. I'll look at it in detail this weekend.